# $n$ choose $k$ vertices given adjacency matrix for undirected graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I wonder if there is a method for calculating the number of (unordered) combinations of $k$ pairwise non-adjacent vertices from an $n$-vertex undirected graph with a given adjacency matrix.

Comment: Probably not, since determining whether the number of combinations of size $k$ is nonzero is the independent set problem, which is NP complete.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you for your reply. I've written a C code to go through all such combinations using the adjacency matrix, but hoped it might be excessive.

Comment: Of course you don't have to write this yourself. There are plenty of clique algorithm implementations that can do it for you.

Comment: @Steven, thank you. It seems this has already been invented. :-) Mine looks very much like the ones that can be found by the key words "clique algorithms".